# how to delete data where number of days > 30

Tags: php

i am new in php
i have a table

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              seeker                             |
+----+-------+----------+---------------+-------------------------+
| id | name  | password | register_date | login_date | limit_date |
+----+-------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+
| 01 | ali   |   ****   |  2012-02-08   | 2012-02-09 | 2012-03-09 |
| 02 | hamza |   ****   |  2012-04-10   | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |
| 03 | sam   |   ****   |  2012-04-15   | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |
+----+-------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

i have to apply two queries
one to delete data when limit date = current date

second to delete data when user login_date is '0000-00-00' and its (register_date - current date) >= 30

my first query is implementing properly

in my second query i am finding no of days by subtracting register_date from current date, if no of days greater than or equal to 30 then delete that user.

my problem is that when an any single user return no of days >= 30 then all user of login_date ='0000-00-00' get deleted.
 here is my code

```
    //code for  delete user where (current date - register date)>=30
    $qry="select * from seeker where login_date='0000-00-00'";
    $rs= mysql_query($qry, $con);
     $res=mysql_num_rows($rs);
    echo "total rows of zero dates "."".$res;
    echo "<br>";
    if($res!=0)
    {
        echo "user exist of date='0000-00-00'";
        echo"<br>";
        $qqq="select * from seeker where login_date='0000-00-00'";
            $rsq= mysql_query($qqq, $con);
            while($resq=mysql_fetch_array($rsq))
            //echo $resq;
        {
          $r=$resq['c_date'];
          echo $r;
          $reg_date = strtotime($r); 
          echo "<br>";

    //current date
        $c= date("Y-m-d");
        echo $c;
        //echo "current date".""."<br>";
        $current_date = strtotime($c); 
        echo "<br>";

         //date difference
          $datediff = $current_date - $reg_date;
          $days = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
          echo "days"."".$days;
          echo "<br>";

        if($days>=30)
        {
        $qry1="delete from seeker where $days = '30'";
        $rs1= mysql_query($qry1, $con);
        echo $qry1;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        }
      }

}
// code for delete user where current date = limit date
$qry3="select * from seeker where current_date = limit_date";
$rs3= mysql_query($qry3, $con);
$res3=mysql_num_rows($rs3);
if($res3!=0)
{

        $q= "delete from seeker where current_date = limit_date";
        $rq=mysql_query($q, $con);
        echo "$q";
        echo "<br>";
}
```

please tell me where i made mistake .
 i want to delete only that user whose days >=30, but it deleted all user of login_date ='0000-00-00'

```
for example if current date is 2012-01-10. it will not delete user
if current date is 2012-05-10.. it must delete only "hamza" but it delets "sam" too
```

please help me, i am student and new in php. thanks in advance

Comment: There is a 70% chance you won't finish this question. I'd suggest dealing with your current open questions before neglecting a new one, or users may not help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please  try `DATEDIFF(time1 ,time2)` function and `NOW()` function in query as given below

```
DELETE FROM seeker WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , `register_date` )  >= 30 AND 
`login_date` = '0000-00-00'
```

thanks.

Comment: thnks @Er. Anurag Jain.. it worked :) i am gonna accept it

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query,

```
DELETE FROM `seeker` 
WHERE `register_date`>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)
```

Comment: thnks for this query. let me try this query @Udhay